Partition of graph into sets A, B, C
I have a graph $(V, E)$ and I need an algorithm (either constructive or using DFS) to split it to three sets $A, B, C$ with properties:

Set $A$ is a path;
|B|=|C|;
$B$ and $C$ are not connected with any edges.

My attempts: I tried different graphs and noticed that this partition might exist for any graph. Please, help me verifying that...
(Algorithm can use DFS and has to be $O(|V|+|E|)$)

Edit: I think I made an oversight in the below example: If the path contains all edges of $K_4$, and the vertices are deleted, then it disconnects the component. So it only works if $A$ is assumed to be a set of edges. Keeping the example below for the sake of the discussion below.
It is definitely not possible to do so in every graph. Consider the following graph:

It consists of two components, one is a triangle, and the other is the complete graph with 4 vertices ($K_4$), and 9 vertices that are connected with each of the vertices of $K_4$ (in the picture, the edges are only drawn for one node). Now: where can the path $A$ be? It must be in the component on the right. The longest possible path in that component has 9 vertices. Any path in the component on the right, when removed, keeps the component on the right connected. Hence after removing any path $A$ from the component on the right, we are left with a component of at least 4 vertices. So we cannot fulfil the condition $|B|=|C|$.

What if we consider that graph is connected? Would this be true?

Should not make a difference for the argument. We can add an extra edge in between the two components. But I now realize that it does not work if the vertices of $A$ are deleted, see edit. Was that how the question was meant?
